# How do you describe "x > y > 5 ", inequality or inequalities?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> x > y > 5   ... (1)

This is a combination of two inequalities; x > y and y > 5 , so should this be described as "inequalities" not "inequality"? For example, which of the following is suitable?

> 1. Solve the inequality (1)
> 2. Solve the inequalities (1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each one

> x > y
>   y > 5

is an *inequality*, stated as

> x > y and y > 5

you could use the *inequalities*, however stated as

> x > y > 5

you could use the *inequality*, it depends how you want to combine them.